# get list of folders from local drive using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I want to delete all the documents(.doc) files from my computer, for that I know how to get the list of sub folders from a folder, but not how to get the list of folders from the root directory(Ex C:)

```
subfoldersInFolder = folder.subFolder
```

Gives all the subfolders of a folder. but supposedly that I want all the folders from C:,

```
 Set colDrives = objFSO.Drives
 For Each objDrive in colDrives
 objDrive.subFolder  //doesn't work
 Next
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
For Each objFolder In objFSO.GetFolder("C:\").SubFolders
    WScript.Echo objFolder.Path
Next

' or...

For Each objFolder In objFSO.GetDrive("C:").RootFolder.SubFolders
    WScript.Echo objFolder.Path
Next
```

*Edit: sundar nataraj Сундар has asked that I go into more detail.*

This is a basic `For` loop that iterates the `SubFolders` collection. The `SubFolders` property is only available for a `Folder` object. You can get a `Folder` object for the root in a number of ways. Here are two examples:

1. Use the `GetFolder()` function to retrieve a root folder.
2. Use the `RootFolder` property of a `Drive` object.

I've added a `WScript.Echo` statement in each example to demonstrate the use of the `objFolder` variable.

Comment: please provide appropriate explanation to your answer so that OP and other users learn better

Answer (score 0):

The [drive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts2t8ybh(v=vs.84).aspx) object doesn't have a SubFolder property. What it does have is a [RootFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6136s633(v=vs.84).aspx) property using which you can navigate to the root **folder** and then on using the **SubFolder** property of the folder object, get all the containing folders just like Mr @Bond mentioned.
However, if you would like to loop through all the folders of all the drives, this will do it

```
On Error Resume Next
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colDrives = FSO.Drives
For Each objDrive in colDrives
    For Each objFolder In FSO.GetFolder(objDrive.RootFolder).SubFolders
        For Each subfolder in objFolder.SubFolders
            WScript.Echo subfolder.Size
    Next
Next
```

You might want to skip through the folders that you are not authorized to access. Hence the first statement.