# Windows Script Host Error 800A004C when running script on network pc

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to change shortcuts on all my PCs on the network that have two target paths to a new server target path, for example `\\server1\folder`, `\\server2\folder` to my new server `\\newserver\folder`. I am trying to see if I can get this working so I don't have to manually touch every PC and check for the shortcuts.

I found a code a user on Spiceworks wrote but can't seem to get it to work to scan all my PCs on the network and user accounts. If I specify to scan `\\pcname\Users\employee\desktop` it works but if I do `\\pcname\Users\%userprofile%\desktop` it gives me the error code in the title.

The link to the script is here https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/298-change-shortcut-lnk-target-paths-in-bulk

Expected outcome should be an html file that opens up saying these shortcuts were changed. The outcome I am getting is

```
Line 232
Char 4
Error Path not found
Code 800A004C
Source Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

Comment: Did you substitute the literal `%userprofile%` into a path in a script, thinking this will automatically apply the script to all possible values of `%userprofile%` that exist on the computer?

Comment: I did.  I have minimal scripting experience unfortunately so I tried researching variables I could plug in.

Comment: There is no magic in scripting. If you have access rights to `\\pcname\users`, [enumerate its subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24452614/11683) and run the script or each folder.

Comment: The link to the script is dead for me. Please [edit] the question and add a [mcve]. BTW, `%userprofile%` does not expand in _vbscript_. Try something like `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "\\pcname\Users\%username%\desktop")`.